# how to implement Search feature in ios 7?

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar

I am working on ios 7 app, I am developing animals details app. I have created first table view for animals category list, second tableview for list of animals in a particular category and third web view for animals detailed web view. I need to implement search feature in first screen that should display search items depends on user queries. How to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Implement search on an array through which you create your first tableview.

1. Take a tempArray for holding the sorted data from the initial tableView.

tempArray = [NSmutableArray alloc]init];

2.For ex lets say user enter a search string "S".

3.Loop through your array from which you created your first tableView.

```
for(int i = 0, i< [yourArray count], i++)
{
NSString *str = [yourArray objectAtIndex:i];
if ([str rangeOfString:@"S"].location == NSNotFound) {
NSLog(@"str does not contain your searched string");
} else {
[tempArray addObject:str];
}

}
```

Now Reload your tableview using your tempArray.

Just for showing the core functionality i have used a static string entered by user, you can create it dynamic using property and assigned it a string entered by user then implement the search.